# Execute Combine Future in background thread is not working

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, future, combine

If you run this on a Playground:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

struct User {
    let name: String
}

var didAlreadyImportUsers = false

var importUsers: Future<Bool, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        sleep(5)
        promise(.success(true))
    }
}

var fetchUsers: Future<[User], Error> {
    Future { promise in
        promise(.success([User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]))
    }
}

var users: AnyPublisher<[User], Error> {
    if didAlreadyImportUsers {
        return fetchUsers
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return importUsers
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
            .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .combineLatest(fetchUsers)
            .map { $0.1 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
}

users
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print(completion)
}, receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
})

print("run")
```

the output will be:

```
[User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]
run
finished
```

But I was expecting to get:

```
run
[User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]
finished
```

Because the sink should run the code in background thread. What I'm missing here. 
Do I need to rin the code:

```
 sleep(5)
 promise(.success(true))
```

in a background thread ? then what's the purpose of

```
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Future runs as soon as it's created, so in your case as soon as this property is accessed:

```
var importUsers: Future<Bool, Never> {
  Future { promise in
    sleep(5)
    promise(.success(true))

  }
}
```

And since the `Future` runs immediately, that means the closure passed to the promise is executed right away, making the main thread sleep for 5 seconds before it moves on. In your case the `Future` is created as soon as you access `users` which is done on the main thread.

`receive(on:` affects the thread that `sink` (or downstream publishers) receive values on, not where they are created. Since the futures are already completed by the time you call `.sink`, the completion and emitted value are delivered to the `sink` immediately. On a background queue, but still immediately.

After that, you finally hit the `print("run")` line.

If you replace the `sleep(5)` bit with this:

```
var importUsers: Future<Bool, Never> {
  Future { promise in
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
      promise(.success(true))
    }
  }
}
```

and make some minor tweaks to your subscription code:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

users
  .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print(completion)
  }, receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
  }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

You'll see that the output is printed as expected because that initial future doesn't block the main thread for five seconds.

Alternatively, if you keep the sleep and subscribe like this you would see the same output:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

users
  .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print(completion)
  }, receiveValue: { value in
    print(value)
  }).store(in: &cancellables)
```

The reason for that is that you `subscribe` on a background thread, so the subscription and everything is set up off the main thread asynchronously which causes `print("run")` to run before receiving the `Future`'s result. However, the main thread still slept for 5 seconds as soon as the `users` property is accessed (which is on the main thread) because that's when you initialize the `Future`. So the entire output is printed all at once and not with a 5 second sleep after `"run"`.

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score 6):

There is a convenient way to reach the expected. Combine has a [Deferred](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/deferred) publisher which waits until `subscribe(on:)` is receiver. So that the code should be something like this

```
var fetchUsers: Future<[User], Error> {
    return Deferred {
        Future { promise in
            sleep(5)
            promise(.success([User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]))
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

fetchUsers
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated))
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)
    }).store(in: &cancellables)

print("run")
```

Such code won't stop main queue and the output will be as expected

```
run
[User(name: "John"), User(name: "Jack")]
finished
```